# error installing python package dragnet

Tags: python

> pip install dragnet

On Windows 7 (I'm new to python)

I cannot resolve the error below ... (thanks for your help)

```
    mozsci/cspearmanr_by_fast.cc(115) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'si
ze_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    mozsci/cspearmanr_by_fast.cc(127) : error C3861: 'isnan': identifier not fou
nd
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\vola-g.SAVOIE\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\
Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit
status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\vola-g~1.sav\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-jz9isn\\mozsci\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\vola-
g~1.sav\appdata\local\temp\pip-3owhyp-record\install-record.txt --single-version
-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\vola-g~1.sav
\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jz9isn\mozsci\
```

Comment: looks like `dragnet` package depends on `mozsci`, which isn't successfully installed, try installing `mozsci` first: `pip install mozsci`

Comment: thanks but same error when installing mozsci

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, it seems `mozsci` depends on `Cython`, what happens when you try `pip install Cython`

Comment: C:\Users\vola-g.SAVOIE>pip install Cython
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in c:\python27\lib\site-packages